# A certain polynomial P(x) , $x\in R$ when divided by $x-a, x-b,x-c$ leaves the remainders a,b,c respectively....

Tags: functions, polynomials, algebra-precalculus

A certain polynomial P(x) , $x\in R$ when divided by $x-a, x-b,x-c$ leaves the remainders a,b,c respectively. Find the remainder when P(x) is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ is (a,b,c are distinct)

My approach : 
Remainder theorem :
$\Rightarrow P(a) =a, P(b) =b; P(c) =c$

Now as per the  question let the required remainder by R(x) , then $P(x) =(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) Q(x) +R(x) $

Where R(x) is a remainder of at most degree 2. Now from here I am not getting anything which helps me to solve this problems.. please help thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You've come a long way. Note that in your factorization we also have $R(a) = a, R(b) = b, R(c) = c$ (since the first term equals $0$), and $R(x)$ is of degree at most $2$. What does that tell you about the polynomial $R(x) - x$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{#c00}{x\!-\! a_i}\!:\,\ f(x)\equiv a_i\!\iff\! f(x)\equiv x\ $ by $\ \color{#c00}{a_i\equiv x}.\ $ So for distinct $\,a_i\in \{a,b,c\}$

$\ \  x\!-\!a_i\mid f\!-\!a_i\!\!\iff\!   x\!-\!a_i\mid f\!-\!x \!\iff\! {\rm lcm}\{x\!-\!a_i\}\!\mid f\!-\!x\!\iff\!  (x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!c)\mid f\!-\!x$

**Remark** $\ $ This is an example of the **constant case** optimization of the *Chinese Remainder Theorem* (CRT), i.e. an obvious transformation shows that residues have constant value (i.e. independent of the moduli), so CRT reduces to a simple lcm calculation. You can find many more examples of this optimizations in [prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+constant+case+CRT)

Comment: @Anant Thanks, fixed. Bad interaction between my macros and SEs.

Answer (score 0):

$$R(x)=mx^2+nx+t\\P(a)=R(a)=a\\P(b)=R(b)=b\\P(c)=R(c)=c\\P(a)-P(b)=m(a^2-b^2)+n(a-b)=a-b\\m(a+b)+n=1\\P(a)-P(c)=m(a+c)+n=1\\m(a+b-a-c)=0\\m(b-c)=0$$
Note: i substracted $m(a+b)+n=1$ and $m(a+c)+n=1$ Since b and c are distinct,$m=0$ than from $m(a+b)+n=1$ we get that $n=1$ and from $R(a)=a$ we get that $a+t=a$ so $t=0$