# $f(x)$ leaves the same remainder of $2018$ when divided by each of $x+4$, $x-1$, $x+7$, $x+8$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers. If $f(x)$ leaves the same remainder of $2018$ when divided by each of $x+4$, $x-1$, $x+7$, $x+8$, find the value of $d$.

A way to approach this is to solve the set of equations: $f(-4) = f(1) = f(-7) = f(-8) = 2018$, but the computation is really tedious when I try it out. However, I couldn't think of any other way to solve this innocent-looking question. Any hints? Thanks very much.

Comment: Sounds like some application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem on the space of polynomials.

Comment: Compare with, say, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828156/a-certain-polynomial-px-x-in-r-when-divided-by-x-a-x-b-x-c-leaves-the-r?rq=1).

Comment: $f(x) = p(x+4)(x-1)(x+7)(x+8) + 2018$. Here $p = 1$ from the given conditions. Can you go ahead and finish it?

Comment: @sudeep5221 your equation is only true for $x = -4, 1, -7, -8$ but not for other values

Comment: @TYeung It is necessarily true that $$f(x) = p(x)(x+4)(x-1)(x+7)(x+8) + 2018$$for some polynomial $p$ (at all $x$). It just that we also know that $f(x)$ is monic fourth degree, which forces $p(x)$ to be the polynomial $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So I can simplify $f(x)$ to $(x+4)(x-1)(x+7)(x+8) + Ax^2 + Bx + C$, right?

Comment: @TYeung rather $\dots+Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D.$

Comment: @Arthur why must that be true?

Comment: @TYeung Because the polynomial $f(x) - 2018$ has roots at $-4$, $1$, $-7$ and $-8$, and therefore must be a multiple of the polynomial $(x+4)(x-1)(x+7)(x+8)$. So really, it's more like $$f(x)-2018 = p(x)(x+4)(x-1)(x+7)(x+8)$$

Comment: Ok thanks, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this has been practically solved in comments, for closure's sake:

As $P(x)-2018$ is a monic quartic with roots $-4, 1,-7,-8$, by Vieta we must have $d-2018=(-4)(1)(-7)(-8)$.